# How are html strings carried to urls and parsed correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a rich text editor on the front page that creates rich text content, and now I get this content, just like：

```html
<u style="font-size: 60px; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;;"><em><strong><span data-slate-string="true">abc</span></strong></em></u>
```

Now I want to take this into the url and jump to the second page,

```js
const allQuery = encodeURIComponent(`isResult=true&content=${htmlString}`);
const jumpUrl = `${secondPageUrl}?${allQuery}`;
// then go to jumpUrl to open the second page
```

However, when I went to obtain and parse the url content on the second page, there was a problem.

```js
new URL(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href)).searchParams.get('content');
```

I got

```html
<u style="font-size: 60px; font-family:
```

I found that the problem appeared in the place of `font-family`, the html content was cut off, and the html tag could not be completely closed, resulting in the failure to render the content correctly.
What should I do ?

Comment: Did you verify htmlString contains what you think it should? Try putting in a console.log.

Comment: I've already verified it. Please try it yourself

Answer (score 2):

Encoding within encoding is causing the confusion.  Take a look at the result here (a partial [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem described):

```js
const htmlString = '<u style="font-size: 60px; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;;"><em><strong><span data-slate-string="true">abc</span></strong></em></u>';
const allQuery = encodeURIComponent(`isResult=true&content=${htmlString}`);
const jumpUrl = `http://www.test.com/?${allQuery}`;

const newUrl = new URL(decodeURIComponent(jumpUrl));
console.log(newUrl);
```

The resulting URL contains `&` characters, which are going to confuse the structure of that URL entirely.  `&` separates different query string values, so in your code you're only reading the *first* query string value.

It sounds like you want to encode `htmlString` before encoding the rest of the query string keys/values around it:

```
const allQuery = encodeURIComponent(`isResult=true&content=${encodeURIComponent(htmlString)}`);
```

Which you'd then be able to decode as a complete value later:

```js
const htmlString = '<u style="font-size: 60px; font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;;"><em><strong><span data-slate-string="true">abc</span></strong></em></u>';
const allQuery = encodeURIComponent(`isResult=true&content=${encodeURIComponent(htmlString)}`);
const jumpUrl = `http://www.test.com/?${allQuery}`;

const result = new URL(decodeURIComponent(jumpUrl)).searchParams.get('content');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `encodeURIComponent` on only the parameter value, and not use `decodeURIComponent` at all, because `URL` is decoding for you.

```
const allQuery = `isResult=true&content=${encodeURIComponent(htmlString)}`;

// or

const allQuery = new URLSearchParams({
    isResult: 'true',
    content: htmlString,
});
```

```
new URL(window.location.href).searchParams.get('content')
```